# Make youtube-dl show output when used by scripts

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-dl

youtube-dl shows the download progress as a command prompt output messege. It works fine in cmd, but when used by a script, youtube-dl only shows this warning

> WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.

and continues to download the file silently while having any other output hidden.

here is the script

```
import os
link = "example_link"
filename = "C:\Path\to\folder\file.mp4"
command = f'youtube-dl --newline -i -f best -o "{filename}" "{link}"'
print(os.popen(command).read())
```

My goal is to find a way to show the output while the script is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code prints (stdout) the download progress with the same params:

```
import youtube_dl

link = "example_link"
filename = "C:\Path\to\folder\file.mp4"

ytb_opts = {
    'newline':True,
    'ignoreerrors':True,
    'format':'best',
    'outtmpl':filename
    }

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytb_opts)
ydl.download([link])
```

If you need to custom the progress message, you must override the report_progress function in FileDownloader class.